# What's the difference between tsc (TypeScript compiler) and ts-node?

Tags: node.js, typescript, tsc, nestjs, ts-node

I'm very confused about the difference between `tsc` and `ts-node`. I'm learning TypeScript and I usually transpile server `.ts` files with `tsc` command.

Now, I'm approaching [nestjs](https://nestjs.com/) framework, and I see that it uses `ts-node`.

So what's the difference between the two? Which one should I use?

Comment: @jfriend00 can you elaborate your answer? AFAIK tsc will change `import` to the commonjs `require()`, which in turn will load the JavaScript source file (assuming in node_modules).

Comment: Read the first paragraph here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node

Comment: Some discussion at https://www.reddit.com/r/typescript/comments/8vkvzy/typescript_with_node_should_i_use_tsnode_or_tsc/

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The main difference is that `tsc` transpile all the file **according to your tsconfig**.

Instead, `ts-node` will start from the entry file and transpile the file step by step through the tree **based on the import/export**.

Comment: So which one to use and when?

Comment: Its a better practice to use tsc to build your project and then run it with node in production, its also faster

Comment: Sometimes you only need to compile one entrypoint and it's imports - `ts-node` is perfect for that and has no downsides.

Comment: i think that there is a ts-node-dev package which speeds build times up if performance is an issue

Answer (score 22):

Most common practice is that `tsc` is used for production build and `ts-node` for development purposes running in `--watch` mode along with `nodemon`. This is a command i often use for development mode for my node/typescript projects:

```
"dev": "nodemon -w *.ts -e ts -x ts-node --files -H -T ./src/index.ts"
```

Comment: `tsc --watch` could've also been used which uses incremental builds and is faster than `nodemon`..

Comment: I'm wondering which builder should I use to build react applications nowadays

Comment: Quick update on this, ts-node CAN be used in production: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60581617/is-it-a-bad-practise-to-use-ts-node-in-production and there's a faster way than using nodemon: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node-dev

Comment: `Quick update on this, ts-node CAN be used in production`

Yeah no one said it can't, it's just the most common practice.

Comment: thank you for a working sample script in package json

Comment: what is the role of nodemon, if ts-node also have the --watch?

Answer (score 0):

TS-Node can also act as a REPL environment along with compiling.