# typescript in node.js doesn't remove dist folder?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have to manually remove

`dist/app.js` to see the latest changes. I have this start script in my package.json

`"start": "tsc && node dist/app.js"`

is it by default node just keep the dist folder so I have to remove it before I compile it?

Answer (score 1):

To remove the dist folder you can have your `package.json` file as follows:

```json
{
  "name": "sample",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rm -rf dist",
    "build": "tsc",
    "start": "npm run clean && npm run build && node dist/app.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Jayant Malik",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.6",
    "typescript": "^4.1.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TS won't remove files in `dist` folder if it's not during development mode;

See this issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13722

A simple solution would be to remove the dir (you can use [rimraf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rimraf) for OS robustness)

Comment: is using ts-node better than mere ts? in many node project I don't see their start script have something like rimraf

Comment: This is unrelated to the original question, but tldr - use tsc. Read here for more https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51448376/whats-the-difference-between-tsc-typescript-compiler-and-ts-node