# What is the correct way of transpiling?

Tags: typescript, tsc, ts-node

I am using [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) and [ts-node](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node) to execute my script as follows:

```
node -r ts-node/register index.ts
```

This works fine, but the compilation process takes too long so I would like to speed everything up. I noticed, that I might also just transpile the TypeScript file and call the resulting `index.js` directly.

What exactly are the requirements for this? Do I need to use `tsc`, `ts-node`, `ts-node-dev` or `node` to make this work?

Any info that makes me able to execute the `index.js` is appreciated!

Comment: Just run `tsc` on the files in the project?

Comment: It still takes too long to start-up

Comment: Compiling takes some time, but at least that way, you'll be able to compile *once* and be done rather than whenever the script is run - isn't that what you're looking for?

Comment: Debugging already works, but now I would like to get a "production build" where I just execute the "application/script"

Comment: Yes, compiling the TS to JS with `tsc` can give you a production-level build if that's what you want

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I just found this after your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51448376/whats-the-difference-between-tsc-typescript-compiler-and-ts-node which might be the cause of my confusion