# Typescript throwing errors on imported packages

Tags: typescript, apollo-server, typegraphql

New to ts and not sure how to resolve this. When running tsc I am getting compilation errors from type-graphql and apollo-server-core. This doesn't make sense to me as they come with types and type-graphql is literally meant to be used with typescript. Please help me figure this one out, added everything I could find online to my tsconfig to no avail.

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
     "target": "es6",
     "module": "commonjs",
     "lib": ["es5", "es6", "es2017", "dom", "esnext.asynciterable"],
     "skipLibCheck": true,
     "sourceMap": true,
     "outDir": "./dist",
     "moduleResolution": "node",
     "removeComments": true,
     "noImplicitAny": true,
     "strictNullChecks": true,
     "strictFunctionTypes": true,
     "noImplicitThis": true,
     "noUnusedLocals": true,
     "noUnusedParameters": true,
     "noImplicitReturns": true,
     "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
     "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
     "esModuleInterop": true,
     "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
     "experimentalDecorators": true,
     "resolveJsonModule": true
   },
   "exclude": ["./node_modules", "./node_modules/**/*"],
   "include": ["./src/**/*.tsx", "./src/**/*.ts"]
 }
```

and the package.json

```
{
   "name": "kp-api",
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "description": "ketopal api app",
   "main": "index.js",
   "license": "NONE",
   "private": true,
   "devDependencies": {
      "@types/express": "^4.17.11",
      "@types/node": "^8.0.29",
      "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
      "typescript": "3.3.3333"
   },
   "dependencies": {
      "apollo-server-express": "^2.23.0",
      "express": "^4.17.1",
      "graphql": "^15.5.0",
      "pg": "^8.4.0",
      "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
      "type-graphql": "^1.1.1",
      "typeorm": "0.2.32"
   },
   "scripts": {
      "build": "tsc",
      "dev": "nodemon dist/index.js",
      "start": "rm -rf dist; yarn tsc; node dist/index.js",
      "watch": "tsc -w"
   }
}
```

Edit:
To answer the first comment, the errors all look like

```
yarn run v1.22.10
$ tsc
node_modules/type-graphql/dist/decorators/unions.d.ts:4:63 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

4 export interface UnionTypeConfig<TClassTypes extends readonly ClassType[]> extends ResolveTypeOptions<UnionFromClasses<TClassTypes>> {
                                                                ~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/type-graphql/dist/decorators/unions.d.ts:4:72 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

4 export interface UnionTypeConfig<TClassTypes extends readonly ClassType[]> extends ResolveTypeOptions<UnionFromClasses<TClassTypes>> {
...
```

Comment: What are the errors thrown?

Comment: updated the question with examples, there are 42 total errors so didn't want to paste them all

Comment: Also, I don't know if this helps, but I saw a post about ts-node so I decided to try it and ```npx ts-node src/index.ts``` doesn't throw any errors. I am so confused.

Comment: This sometimes happens when your TS is outdated - try bumping it up - the current version is 4.2.4. Your type-graphql is pretty old too and is set not to update.

Comment: you're not excluding node_modules -https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#examples - try "exclude": ["node_modules"],

Comment: tsc and ts-node do not load the files the same way. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51456915/15304814

Comment: FYI since your new you can also set "baseUrl": "src", and use absolute path import i.e. instead of ../../components/  you can do components/...